# Installing Ubuntu 13.10 on Acer S7 doesn't detect operating system and then gives "??? ???" error

Tags: ubiquity

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 from a USB drive onto an Acer S7 alongside an existing Windows 8 partition.

I've set aside a 30GB partition for the Ubuntu installation.

When I run the installation, it doesn't detect any existing operating system. I've followed [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2108450&p=12486498#post12486498) to the letter - but on the last step of the 'Install Ubuntu' part (the actual installation), I get the following un-Googleable error:

[image: ??? ???]

In case the picture isn't clear enough - it's an error prompt with the message "??? ???". **Clicking on "OK" takes me back to the first page in the installation (the one telling me that no operating system is detected). Pressing 'continue' is not an option because of the error prompt.**

Is anyone familiar with this? How can I fix this error and install Ubuntu?

Comment: +1 for 5 more rep. Edited post anyway *(it will need to be peer reviewed first)*, using a 'automatic perspective' tool. I know the install starts before you pick your time zone, but does it jam after pressing 'Continue'? Perhaps running a check on your USB's image, and finding a better internet connection will help. By the way, instrcutions are [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest) as well.

Comment: Did you click to install beside Windows 7? If so, try something else and manually configure where it is to install - more [here](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/), go down to Step 7-C

Comment: @wilf Pressing continue isn't an option because of the error prompt (the only option is pressing OK, which takes me back to the first page in the installation).. How can I run a check on my USB's image? I can run Ubuntu directly from the USB without any problems so I don't think that that's the problem.. And why is internet connection a factor? As far as I can tell, it's optional in the installation.

Comment: I didn't click to install besides Windows (8) because it didn't recognize the operating system. This is apparently a common issue, in my question I linked to a guide that is supposed to fix the problem, but gives the "??? ???" error for me.

Comment: Create `/boot` as a separate partition - I always do that, and sometimes for `/var` as well due to error logs choking the hard drive.

Comment: @wilf I don't quite understand - when I choose the remaining free space for the Ubuntu partition, are you saying that I should change mount point to /boot rather than /?

Comment: @Alvar The installer does not work - I have no option of continuing the installation process and pressing "OK" in the error prompt takes me back to the first page in the installation.

Comment: Create `/boot` as well as `/` and swap. It should prompt you if you leave anything out.

Comment: @wilf Meaning I should make a third partition with mount point /boot? What type should it be?

Comment: No the `/boot` first, then `/` and then swap. It has to go first, as that is where the bootloader (Grub) scans when booting.

Comment: A "??? ???" error message is definitely a bug. (It would likely be considered a bug *even* if it's a result of corrupted installation media, provided it results from more than one bad image/device.) I recommend anyone still having this problem [report it as one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem on my computer (same model).  It seemed like it was a problem with setting up the partions because after that error, when I would restart the installation the root and swap partitions did not show up as ext4 and swap.  I dropped to the live USB, ran GPARTED and created these two partitions for myself.  Then, I did the installation and it worked perfectly.